# Taking multiple lines of input in Python from the system.in

Tags: python, input

For one of my assignments, rather than reading directly from a text file, we are directly taking the input from `sys.in`. I was wondering what the best way of obtaining this input and storing it would be?
So far, I've tried using:

`sys.stdin.readlines()` -- But this will not terminate unless it recieves an EOF statement, while a zero in my input signals the end of the file.

`sys.stdin.readline()` -- It will only read the final line of the input code.

`input()` -- I can only read in the first line of the input and when I try to loop it, I end up with a syntax error.

An example of the input is below:

```
3
2 1 3
3 2 1
1 3 2
2 1 3
3 2 1
1 3 2
2
1 2
1 2
2 1
2 1
0
```

My attempt at obtaining the input:

```
input_list = []

    while True:
        input_str = input("")
        if input_str == '0':
            break
        else:
            input_list.append(input_str)

    print(input_list)
```

Returns this error while parsing the second line through:

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've probably spent longer trying to get the input to work now than the actual assignment now.

EDIT: The version of Python we are using is 3.4

FINAL EDIT: Like both the answers said, it turns out that the university labs have a older version of python running when run in cmd prompt in the labs, where the input() method started behaving differently. Once I tried the code at home, it worked as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `input()` as this behaves differently for different versions of Python. Instead, you can read from `sys.stdin`, this should work:

```
import sys

input_list = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.strip() == '0':
        break
    input_list.append(line)
else:
    print('Warning: EOF occurred before "0" terminator')

print(input_list)
```

The for loop will terminate when a line with a single `0` is read, or when EOF is seen. The `else` lets you handle the case when the input terminates before `0` is seen; you can treat that as an error if that suits your application.

For your input, the output would be:

```
['3\n', '2 1 3\n', '3 2 1\n', '1 3 2\n', '2 1 3\n', '3 2 1\n', '1 3 2\n', '2\n', '1 2\n', '1 2\n', '2 1\n', '2 1\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

For *Python 2.x* , you should use `raw_input()` .

In *Python 2.x* , using `input()` would actually try to evaluate the whatever was inputted, which can lead to issues (like the one you encountered) , and is dangerous (since it evaluates whatever the user inputs) .

`raw_input()` would not evaluate the inputted value, but would only return it as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately we are using python 3.4 at the moment, I'll edit the post now to adknowledge that .

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Try creating a script - `import sys; print(sys.version)` , and then run the script (without specifying `python` executable , like you did for your actual code).

Comment: Yep, the current version is :


`3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31)`

Comment: And you surely created a new script for this and ran? Or just add that line to the start of your `hoopla.py` and again run the same code and try to update the question with the new screenshot for that.

Comment: It seems like you were right, when I ran it through cmd this time it came up with 2.7.3 . Im terribly sorry! Is there a way that I can specify which version of python the script should run? 
Thanks.

Comment: When did it come up as Python 3? Try doing just Python in command line , which version comes up ?

Comment: When I was using Notepad++, with the command line, it comes up with 2.7.3